# Pycharm output is being displayed different from other interpreters

Tags: python, pycharm

When I excecute the following code, the output is displayed incorrectly in Pycharm. The tab character spacing is showing different in pycharm vs other online python interpreters or jupyter notebook.

```
organisms = int(input('Starting number of organisms: '))
increase = float(input('Average daily increase in percent (eg: 5 or 6): '))
days_to_multiply = int(input('Number of days for organisms to multiply: '))

print('Day Approximate\t Population')

for day in range(1,days_to_multiply + 1):
    print(day,'\t\t',organisms)
    organisms = organisms + organisms * (increase/100)
```

The output days and population are not aligned under 'Day Approximate' and 'Population' row respectively. 
Output from Pycharm:
[image]

Output from jupyter and online python interpreter - https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter
[image]
The population output is aligned under 'Population'

Comment: long time ago `tab` was deffined as 8 spaces and some programs still use 8 spaces for `tab` - so better use spaces or use string formatting for this. ie. `print("{:<8} {}".format(day, organisms))`

Comment: @furas So how many spaces are being used by PyCharm here vs other interpreters? Also, why is the output of `print('Day Approximate\t Population')` the same for both PyCharm and other interpreters ?

Comment: `\t` doesn't put exactly 4 spaces but fill text to 4 chars - when you print one char then `\t` will add 3 spaces, when you have 2 chars then `\t` will add 2 spaces, etc. Other word - after `tab` text will start in column, 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, etc. - a multiple of 4. Similar when tab fill text to 8 chars then next text will start in column: 8th, 16th, etc. - a multiple of 8. Text `'Day Approximate'` has length `15` so the nearest multiple of 4 is 16, and the nearest multiple of 8 is also 16. So in both situation you get the same result for first line.

Comment: @furas - So in this case, which program is using 8 spaces for tab? Is there a way to make Pycharm print output like other interpreters by adjusting settings?

Comment: it is clear that Pycharm uses 4 spaces because in second line second column is nearer left size then in other programs. Probably in PyCharm you can change length of tab but I would rather use string formattiong - i.e `print("{:<16} {}".format(day, organisms))`. It will display correctly even If you give it to someone who has different settings for tabs.

Comment: for Python 3.6+ you can even use f-string like `print(f"{day:<16} {organisms}")`

Comment: It's weird now. If I use`print("{:<8} {}".format(day, organisms))` in pycharm and jupyter notebook, the output is the same. It's like pycharm where the 2 line of output is not alligned with under Population. In the online interpreter, it's giving me a syntax error. 
Edit: If I use :<16, it is alligned in both Pycharm and Jupyter but syntax error in online interpreter.

Comment: If I use :<16, it is alligned in both Pycharm and Jupyter but syntax error in online interpreter but once I reloaded the website, it's displaying it correctly. Thanks.